# Congruent issue

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I'm studying a proof of Erdos Chao Ko Rado theorem and I'm stuck somewhere.

Here is the problem : Let $n$ be a natural number and $0<k\leqslant n/2$. Let $B_i$ be the set of those numbers among $1,2,...,n$ which are congruent, $\bmod n$, to one of
$$
(i-1)k+1, (i-1)k+2,\dots,ik.
$$
The proof says that $B_1$ is non-disjoint with $B_j$ if and only if either
$$
jk=q_1n + r_1 \quad \text{or}\\
(j-1)k+1=q_2n+r_2
$$
where $0\leqslant q_1,q_2<k$ and $0<r_1,r_2\leqslant k$.

May I have some help please?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math.SE. The question is pretty hard to parse visually. You should learn some MathJax, see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Thanks ! I was on my phone. Next time i'll use MathJax !